# Cast Between Incompatible Function Types in gcc

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a code generation script that was written by someone else around 2008 and has worked fine mostly unchanged since then. Just recently I tried compiling with gcc9 and I see 7300 warnings for "cast between incompatible function types" in the generated code.

The code takes a set of function pointers and various type identifiers and inserts everything into a big map that's used later for option serialization, printing, etc. Many functions and variables are cast and stored as some form of void *. The code otherwise compiles with no errors and works properly.

I tried various C-style casts, reinterpret_cast, and casting the function pointer to void(*)(void), but none of them remove the warnings. What's the correct way to cast the function to a generic type to avoid this warning? The only solution I can come up with is disabling -Wcast-function-type.

Here is one example line that generates warnings:

```
pim.must_find("input_fn")->set_introspect_info( sizeof(filename_t), ((char *)(&p_cn->input_fn)) - ((char *)p_cn), 0,invalid_offset, (str_from_base_t *)str_from_filename_t, (send_base_t *)send_filename_t, (recv_base_t *)recv_filename_t, (val_from_param_t *)val_from_param_filename_t, 0);
```

The warning is related to these two functions:

```
typedef std::string str_from_base_t( void const * );

std::string str_from_filename_t( filename_t const & v ) { return v; }
```

Where filename_t is a class that interits from std::string.

Note that there are dozens of different str_from_***() functions that have different classes as arguments.

The warning I get is:

```
../src/gen/DEFReader_PostParam.cc: In function 'void croix::DEFReaderCLI_introspect_pim_init()':
../src/gen/DEFReader_PostParam.cc:25:153: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'std::string (*)(const croix::filename_t&)' {aka 'std::basic_string<char> (*)(const croix::filename_t&)'} to 'std::string (*)(const void*)' {aka 'std::basic_string<char> (*)(const void*)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
25 |  pim.must_find("input_fn")->set_introspect_info( sizeof(filename_t), ((char *)(&p_cn->input_fn)) - ((char *)p_cn), 0,invalid_offset, (str_from_base_t *)str_from_filename_t, (send_base_t *)send_filename_t, (recv_base_t *)recv_filename_t, (val_from_param_t *)val_from_param_filename_t, 0);
```

Comment: *What's the correct way to cast the function to a generic type to avoid this warning?* -- Why do you believe there is a "correct" way?  Maybe what you were doing was incorrect, and so far up until now you were never bitten by it.  Applying C-style casts to avoid compiler warnings and errors is a sign that at some point, something may go wrong.

Comment: Okay, then what's the correct way to insert function pointers that take a variety of different single class arguments into the same map? I need to find a cleaner way to make this work without rewriting everything, given that I don't completely understand how this whole system is supposed to work. This is the option processing part of a large commercial software code base.

Comment: The way it should have been designed is to use function objects, and have the parameters part of the function object members.  Then derive from a base object, and each child class overrides `operator ()`.  I know this is not an answer, but as a guide in how to prevent getting into this situation in the future.

Comment: [Here is a tiny example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d77ff1baa9c5c619).  One single map, multiple "functions", all having different signatures, and absolutely no casting was done, and no `void*`.  The trick is that the parameters have been moved from the function invocation to the member variables, and the magic of `operator()` comes into play.

Comment: *I need to find a cleaner way to make this work without rewriting everything, given that I don't completely understand how this whole system is supposed to work.* -- I don't think you need to understand the complete system.  You know what that map and casting is supposed to do (theoretically).  So it's a matter of reimplementing it knowing what the end results should be.  It would be a different story if you had no idea what purpose the map had, what a function pointer is, etc.

Comment: I see what you've done, and this seems like a good way to do it with classes. However, many of the types my system was meant to work with are primitives such as uint8_t, uint32_t, float, double, etc. and these can't be used in inheritance. The code generation scans existing code for variable definitions matching a certain pattern and generates the code to serialize them, print them, send them over the network, write them to disk, etc. So you can have a struct/class with member variables of any of the 31 supported types and it would be able to generate code to print/send/write that class.

Comment: [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/763adefb182b0e6f).  The primitives are wrapped in a template class and are accessible by using the casting operator (see the last line in `main`).  It just takes a little thinking outside the "C-programmer" box of `void *` to see the potential in doing things this way.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this. The problem is, my serialization code is run on 301 different classes and 2222 total member variables. It would be a huge amount of work to change all of them to be of a new type and update all of the users to access the nested primitives.

Comment: The user wouldn't know that the primitive is actually a class.  Look at how I declared `double` and `int` at the end.  I know it is a lot of classes, but you should start from somewhere.  Maybe (using git-speak) fork your code to a new branch and work on the changes, while still running the current code with the ill-advised casts, hoping it won't break?

Comment: This was designed to be a non-intrusive way to serialize existing classes. The code is all generated by python. You just tell it which classes to serialize and it parses the class definitions, identifies the variable names and types, and creates a map from {variable_name, function_pointer} which is used in serialization. Then we iterate over the map and call the functions to generate strings of the form "key="+iter->key+",value="+iter->value->str_from_base(pointer)" where pointer is the address of the class plus some member variable offset that's precomputed and also stored in the map.

Comment: Your suggestion is a good way to do it if I was starting over again from scratch. It solves the issue of using the variables. But I'm still stuck with changing all of the classes and member variables. There may also be performance issues. So far no one has been able to come up with a solution, and the original author of the system has left the company.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the correct way to cast the function to a generic type?

The answer is that there is no correct way. The warning is absolutely justified.

The point is that you have a typesafe function that you can pass only `filename_t` and you cast it to something that can take literally anything. The only way to not run into undefined bahavior is to still pass it a `filename_t` even though you now *could* pass anything else.

That yields the question of why you need to cast it to a generic type? You say that those functions get stored in a map with some type identifiers. Now, due to limited information it is hard to judge on this, but to me this sounds a little like artificially building a mechanism that choses the right function for you, while there is a perfectly working built in mechanism for this: function overload resolution.

So, at some point in the code you must have a `filename_t` object at hands. Then (I'm assuming) you infer some type identifier from it and use that to look up the proper function in a map. Then you pass your `filename_t` as a `void*` there, knowing that it will work.

I'm sure it's much more complex than this, but maybe you can identify this part of the logic and get rid of it: get rid of the map (at least that part that maps type identifiers to functions) and just call the function directly at a time where you still know the type (because then overload resolution will do the trick for you).

Templates can help you to keep the types instead of making everything `void*`.

Comment: Or if dynamic binding and `virtual` isn't an issue, function objects with an overridden call operator from a base class can be utilized.  The parameters then need not be casted to `void *`, since the derived function object has this information.  Either way, templates or dynamic binding, the OP's C-style casting stuff is a definite bad way to do this.

Comment: The difficult part is that this has to work with member variables of a struct/class, including ints and floats. The code generation builds a map that can be used to serialize, etc. the set of member variables. It's built on top of the existing code, so I can't just modify every class member to inherit from some base class.

Comment: Function overloading will work for some types, but the more complex types are defined externally and not available to the serialization code. I get compile errors that the function doesn't exist. Templates are similar, it's unclear where I can declare the template functions such that all of the code has access to them.

Comment: For a real-world example of this, the Python C API's PyMethodDef table structure requires incompatible casts of this sort. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMethodDef

Comment: See dlsym(). https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html. It just uses a void* and is assumed to be castable to some usable type.