# What's the "right" way to type-erase a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am writing a test fixture which involves ensuring certain callbacks are called at appropriate times (actually Qt signals, but it shouldn't matter for the sake of my problem). To help with this, I created a helper class that records when a callback (signal) fires into a list.

This list needs to be able to record *which* callback (signal) fired. I would also prefer to not need to create a new enumeration specifically for this purpose. My idea was to instead record the address of the signal as a type-erased pointer so I can check the record against the address of the signal.

To make things a little easier on myself, I record the signal type as a:

```cpp
template <typename Object>
class SignalType
{
public:
  SignalType() = default;
  SignalType(SignalType const&) = default;
  SignalType(SignalType&&) = default;

  template <typename R, typename... Args>
  SignalType(R (Object::*member)(Args...))
    : member{reinterpret_cast<void (Object::*)()>(member)} {}

  template <typename R, typename... Args>
  bool operator==(R (Object::*other)(Args...)) const
  { return this->member == reinterpret_cast<void (Object::*)()>(other); }

private:
  void (Object::*member)() = nullptr;
};
```

This "hides" the type erasure from the point of use, so I can later just write:

```cpp
QCOMPARE(event.type, &SomeObject::someMethod);
```

...without needing to clutter that with a cast.

However, GCC is unhappy:

```
warning: cast between incompatible pointer to member types from ‘void (SomeObject::*)(...)’ to ‘void (SomeObject::*)()’ [-Wcast-function-type]
```

Is there a way to make GCC happy without resorting to diagnostic `#pragma`s to simply shut up the warning? Is there some other, "better" way to achieve this particular flavor of type-erasure? (Note that I don't need to ever *call* the member that `SignalType` encapsulates; I just need to be able to test for equality.)

---

Sigh. Should search on the warning message, not what I'm trying to do. *Technically* I guess this is a duplicate of [Cast Between Incompatible Function Types in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014469), however that only asks how to get rid of the warning, and isn't clear what the code is trying to accomplish. So, in order that I might learn something useful here, please focus on if there is some other, "cleaner" way to accomplish my goal rather than just closing this as a duplicate and saying "it can't be fixed".

Comment: You could use `std::any`. If any-casting to the same pointer to member type fails, then you know that it isn't the same function. If it succeeds, then compare the values.

Comment: @eerorika, unfortunately this needs to compile on GCC 4.8; `std::any` is not available until C++17... and using boost is absolutely out of the question. That said, how does `std::any` avoid having the same problem internally? (Or does it?)

Comment: gcc 4.8 is rather ancient, maybe consider to upgrade?

Comment: @idclev463035818, I am painfully aware (you are preaching to the choir; I would be *thrilled* to drop support for GCC 4.8). Unfortunately, that is the latest available on many Red Hat systems that I am required to support.

Comment: Take a peak at the implementation of boost::any, see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/boost/any.hpp. You could minimize it to your needs and expand the `class placeholder` it with an `virtual bool equals(const placeholder& rhs) const = 0;`

Comment: @dalle, yeah... I'd really prefer a solution that doesn't require heap allocation and virtual methods. Something something mutter cannon something mutter mosquito...

Comment: Possibly you can shut the warning by comparing with `memcmp` if that counts.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev, comparing is only half the problem. I also need to be able to type-erase the pointer in order to record it (in a member value that needs to be able to hold "any" member function type).

Comment: Why, if you don't mind `memcmp`, then you shouldn't mind `memcpy` ing into `char data[sizeof(void (Object::*)())]`

Comment: @Matthew you asked for the "right way", but if you don't like the answer  to that question because it uses virtual functions and heap allocation, you should edit that detail into your question.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev, right. Also, d'oh . Actually, I don't even need a char buffer? I can just declare `SignalType::member` as now and take its address as the `memcpy` destination.

Comment: Sure, if the purpose is to avoid warning about invalid type case, this should be enough. I'd also `static_assert` about size of different member pointers being the same.
It is based on the assumption that the value of unrelated pointers of different types is different, but I can't imagine how they can have the same value.

Comment: (Another assumption is taken for `memcmp` solution is that the same pointer have the same value. This one needs checking against the implementation, if there are unused bits)

Comment: Possibly safer would be to `memcpy` both source and comparand to a known pointer type, then compare it as a pointer. Then you'll get rid of unused bits problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that holds a function pointer that can compare two values of the same type whilst also acting as a `std::type_info` checking at run time if two types are the same. It stores the function pointer in a `char[]`.

```cpp
#include <new>

template<typename Object>
class SignalType
{
public:
  SignalType() = default;
  SignalType(SignalType const&) = default;
  SignalType& operator=(SignalType const&) = default;

  template<typename R, typename... Args>
  SignalType(R (Object::*member)(Args...)) noexcept
    : comparator(&compare_members_from_void_ptr<R, Args...>) {
    using member_ptr_type = R(Object::*)(Args...);
    static_assert(sizeof(member_ptr_type) <= sizeof(void(Object::*)()), "Member pointer type too large?");
    static_assert(alignof(member_ptr_type) <= alignof(void(Object::*)()), "Member pointer align too large?");
    // Don't need to destruct since it has a trivial destructor
    new (member_storage) member_ptr_type(member);
  }

  bool operator==(const SignalType& other) const {
    if (!comparator) return !other.comparator;  // Check both empty
    // Same comparator implies same type
    return comparator == other.comparator && comparator(member_storage, other.member_storage);
  }
  bool operator!=(const SignalType& other) const {
    return !(*this == other);
  }

   // Return true if these contain pointers to members of the same type
  bool is_same_type_as(const SignalType& other) const {
    return comparator == other.comparator;
  }

  // true if holding a typed pointer (could still be nullptr)
  explicit operator bool() const {
    return comparator;
  }

  // Check if holding an `R(Object::*)(Args...)`
  template<typename R, typename... Args>
  bool is_type() const noexcept {
    return comparator && comparator == &compare_members_from_void_ptr<R, Args...>;
  }

  // Returns the held function pointer if it is of type R(Object::*)(Args...), else nullptr
  template<typename R, typename... Args>
  R(Object::* get() const noexcept)(Args...) {
    return is_type<R, Args...>() ? *static_cast<R(Object::**)(Args...)>(static_cast<void*>(member_storage)) : nullptr;
  }
private:
  alignas(void(Object::*)()) char member_storage[sizeof(void(Object::*)())];
  bool (*comparator)(const void*, const void*) = nullptr;

  template<typename R, typename... Args>
  static bool compare_members_from_void_ptr(const void* a, const void* b) noexcept {
    return *static_cast<R(Object::*const *)(Args...)>(a) == *static_cast<R(Object::*const *)(Args...)>(b);
  }
};
```

Comment: What's the value of the additional type safety? AFAIK, two different member functions can never have the same address anyway?

Comment: @Matthew I've done some thinking and I *think* that `memcmp` will always be the same as `==` as long as they aren't both nullptrs. Two null pointer-to-member functions can compare unequal with `memcmp` (See https://godbolt.org/z/KtTBLP), but there might be more edge cases, so this is the safe standards-compliant way of doing it